# DUPLICACION DE CARPETA PHP EN PROYECTO

Tags: php, html

estoy creando un proyecto sencillo de una calculadora con un formulario de HTML y PHP. Cree una carpeta para mi archivo PHP, y le indique la ruta al `action` del formulario, en el PHP quiero que el usuario no deba dar atrás, así que añadí un `include` para que los inputs se vuelvan mostrar en la página de la respuesta, al hacer la primera operación funciona, al realizar una segunda ya estando en la URL terminada en PHP, me lanza un error de archivo no encontrado y me duplica la carpeta de PHP en la URL.

También me gustaría saber si crear las carpetas de esta forma califica como una buena práctica, gracias por su ayuda.

El código es el siguiente:

HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="php/server.php" method="post">

        Numero 1 <input type="number" name="numero1">
        Numero 2 <input type="number" name="numero2">

        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP:

```php
<?php
include "../index.html";

$numero1 = 0;
$numero2 = 0;
$resultado = 0;

if(isset($_POST['numero1']) && isset($_POST['numero2'])){

    $numero1 = $_POST['numero1'];
    $numero2 = $_POST['numero2'];

    $resultado = $numero1 + $numero2;

    echo "El resultado es $resultado";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando una direccion relativa en el formulario.

Entiendo que tus dos archivos están de esta forma en la estructura:

```
/index.html
/php/serverphp
```

Para el primer envió estas en la carpeta raíz "/" y con "php/server.php" buscas dentro de la carpeta actual una carpeta "php"

Cuando haces la segunda consulta estas en el archivo "/php/server.php" por lo que estas dentro de la carpeta "/php/" y cuando envías el formulario estas buscando la carpeta "php" dentro de "/php/" es decir "/php/php/server.php" que es el error que creo que te esta dando.

Para solucionarlo cambia el formulario de una ruta relativa a una absoluta para que siempre apunte al mismo archivo agregándole la raíz al principio de la dirección "/php/server.php"

```
<form action="/php/server.php" method="post">
```

## Edito

Perdón he estado leyendo ya que no lo tenia muy fresco y al parecer empezar desde la raíz también se considera una ruta relativa, la absoluta solo es cuando se escribe el dominio completo "http://www.web.com/php/server.php", en tu caso con empezar desde la raíz ya es suficiente.

Comment: Se considera ruta relativa siempre y cuando no empieces desde... bueno, desde el principio :) Lo único que cambia es la relatividad con respeto a qué, a la raíz del proyecto, a la página actual, a la carpeta padre... pero siguen siendo relativas, solo son absolutas cuando partes del origen, normalmente la unidad de disco: `C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\php\server.php` sería una ruta absoluta, cualquier otro inicio que no sea en la unidad, sería relativa. Obviamente si hablamos de redirecciones web, lo normal es usar la URL y no la unidad de disco, claro :P